# R: Total in the last 365 days window by month

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry if i did something wrong in my first time using stackoverflow, and sorry everyone of you that waste time with me. I talked to some users and i can do something different. 
defaults(today -60 until -365) after that time will have another column called loss, to take the rest of the values.

Thanks everyone who helped me! problem solved!

```
            CASE
            WHEN TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY')-425 <= TO_DATE(TRIM(DT_TRANSACAO),'DD/MM/YY')
            THEN SUM(VL_VENCIDO)
            ELSE 0
            END AS   VL_VENCIDO, ---defaults(today -60 until -365 days ago) 
            CASE
            WHEN TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY')-425 > TO_DATE(TRIM(DT_TRANSACAO),'DD/MM/YY')
            THEN SUM(VL_VENCIDO)
            ELSE 0
            END AS   VL_PDD, --loss more than 425 days ago
         ---acumulated loss and defaults
        sum(VL_PDD) over (order by YEAR, MONTH) AS VL_AC_PDD, 
        sum(VL_VENCIDO) over (order by YEAR, MONTH) AS VL_AC_INADI
```

Thanks folks! And sorry again english is not my best skill!

Comment: could you add the ddl for your table and some sample data?

Comment: OK ill edit my post with more information! Thanks

Comment: Could you post more of your query? Also, if the accumulated total is `current month defaults + all previous months`, shouldn't Jan accumulated be 150?

Comment: How is `TRUNC(SYSDATE-60)` related to 365 days?

Comment: Are you talking about "365 days" or rather "1 year"? In this case I would recommend `ADD_MONTHS(..., -12)`

Comment: https://github.com/joelcjunior/question/blob/master/defaults.sql

Comment: @kfinity yes my mistake sorry!

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit it should be 365 days plus 60 from here SUM(DECODE(CD_TPMOV,'R',DECODE(SIGN(DT_DISPONI - TRUNC(SYSDATE-60)),-1,VL_SALDO,0),0)) as defaults

Comment: add your sql to the question, not as a comment - and the raw source, not a link to a file.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith done thanks and sorry again.

Comment: Please provide some sample data. It is very difficult to understand your requirements.

Comment: `TO_DATE(DT_VENREAL,'DD/MM/YY')` also looks suspicious, is that column actually a date already? (Nothing to do with your question, but still...)

Comment: Ok, now we need to see what VM_001_FLXCAIXA looks like - specifically the data types of the columns in the SELECT field. if you have SQL Developer, you can open the table and click on the 'SQL' page to get the SQL script to create the table

Comment: @thatjeffsmith ok

Comment: Sorry Mr. @WernfriedDomscheit I'm not used to do that foruns thing. If anyhow i have offended you or disrespected you with my question im truly sorry. Almost solve my problem already, if you want to I can delete that post. Or  if you agree i will edit with the resolution after a few hours.

Comment: No problem, I am not offended. Anyway, now your question looks much better than it was before. But we would still need some lines of sample data.

Comment: Now you have some! @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Sorry and ty for the helping!

Comment: @tthatjeffsmith ty you too! Next time ill try to be more clear! your blog helped alot cya!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  CASE
            WHEN TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY')-425 <= TO_DATE(TRIM(DT_TRANSACAO),'DD/MM/YY')
            THEN SUM(VL_VENCIDO)
            ELSE 0
            END AS   VL_VENCIDO, ---defaults(today -60 until -365 days ago) 
            CASE
            WHEN TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY')-425 > TO_DATE(TRIM(DT_TRANSACAO),'DD/MM/YY')
            THEN SUM(VL_VENCIDO)
            ELSE 0
            END AS   VL_PDD, --loss more than 425 days ago
         ---acumulated loss and defaults
        sum(VL_PDD) over (order by YEAR, MONTH) AS VL_AC_PDD, 
        sum(VL_VENCIDO) over (order by YEAR, MONTH) AS VL_AC_INADI
```